# SQL - Calculate Stock Movement By Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008, I have a table that contains columns `Date, ItemID, OpeningStockBalance`.

For example, three days worth of data for three `ItemID`'s below.

```
26/12/2018, 000001, 10
26/12/2018, 000002, 5
26/12/2018, 000003, 15
27/12/2018, 000001, 8
27/12/2018, 000002, 4
27/12/2018, 000003, 14
28/12/2018, 000001, 6
28/12/2018, 000002, 3
28/12/2018, 000003, 10
```

I'd like to derive the sales by day by `ItemID` by starting from the most recent date and working backwards i.e. for `ItemID` 000001 on the 28th the stock balance was 6 but it was 8 on the 27th thus sales of 2 units.

Desired Output (`Date, ItemID, Sales`)

```
27/12/2018, 000001, 2
27/12/2018, 000002, 1
27/12/2018, 000003, 4
26/12/2018, 000001, 2
26/12/2018, 000002, 1
26/12/2018, 000003, 1
```

Apologies in advance for the dreadful formatting but wasn't sure how to new line!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lead()`:

```
select date, itemId,
       (OpeningStockBalance - next_OpeningStockBalance) as sales
from (select t.*,
             lead(OpeningStockBalance) over (partition by itemID order by date) as next_OpeningStockBalance
      from t
     ) t
where next_OpeningStockBalance is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gordon, it's actually version 2008 so sadly can't use lead :(  I've edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

Create the sales column by subtracting the 2 values from adjacent days:

```
select 
  t.date, 
  t.itemid, 
  (select 
    openingstockbalance 
    from stock as s 
    where 
      s.itemid = t.itemid
      and 
      s.date = DATEADD(day, -1, t.date)) - t.openingstockbalance as sales
from stock as t 
where t.date <> (select min(date) from stock)
order by t.date desc, t.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

To imitate lead/lag in 2008 you can add sequence number to your original table and use it in self join (see the code below). However if you just need sales from previous calendar day probably use subselect as other post suggests.

```
,M as (
select T.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by itemID order by date) rn from T
)

select M1.*, (m1.sales - m2.sales) as prev_day_sales
from M M1
 inner join M M2 on m2.ItemID = m1.ItemID and m1.rn = m2.rn - 1
order by 2, 1 desc
```